# One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key Id expected: N actual: S

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I want to insert a key value pair into DynamoDB.

Here is my insert method in the service class:

```
protected PutItemResult insert(String table, String id, String key, String value){
    PutItemRequest request = new PutItemRequest()
        .withTableName(table)
        .addItemEntry("Id", new AttributeValue(id))
        .addItemEntry(key, new AttributeValue(value));
    return dynamoDbClient.putItem(request);
}
```

What I understand from the following error, Id should be a number?

```
One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key Id expected: N actual: S
```

But when I change the method definition:

```
insert(String table, Integer id, String key, String value){
```

I see the following warning:

```
The constructor AttributeValue(Integer) is undefined
```

What is the type of the Id in DynamoDB? How should I define it in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I added withN around id and this solved the problem:

```
protected PutItemResult insert(String table, String id, String key, String value) {
     PutItemRequest request = new PutItemRequest()
        .withTableName(table)
        .addItemEntry("Id", new AttributeValue().withN(id))
        .addItemEntry(key, new AttributeValue(value));
    return dynamoDbClient.putItem(request);
}
```